# Gui Text without background box border?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there a way to write text in a GUI.Window without having a background box surrounding the text?  Basically an alternative to GUI.Label and GUI.Text, since those create the problem as described above.

Comment: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/49212-GUI-Box-with-no-border  does this help?

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to add GUIStyle.none at the end of call GUI.Window:

```
GUI.Window(555, new Rect((Screen.width/2) - 100f, (Screen.height/2) - 60f, 200f,120f), wfunc, "something", GUIStyle.none);
```